# Ignore character using regex (pcre) PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to capture date from a file `file-2018-02-19-second.json`.

I am using `.*file-(..........).*.json` regex to capture the date in the file  .The regex is capturing `2018-02-19` date in the file but I want to ignore `"-"` in the file and only capture `20180219`. How can I do it?

Comment: You either need to pull the date as you are and then remove non-digits i.e. `\D+` replace with nothing or grab each part separately `(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})`

Comment: Make three capture groups. Just using the same principle.

Comment: All the digits in your string belong to the date, [see here](https://eval.in/965302).

Comment: I used .*file-((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}))-.*.json regex for the file file-2018-02-19-second.json , but this will create 3 groups , I need only one group

Answer (score 3):

If your filenames have always the same format, you can convert your string to a DateTime instance using `DateTime::createFromFormat`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('*-Y-m-d-*.*', 'file-2018-02-19-second.json');
echo $date->format('Ymd');
```

You can find the different format characters and their meanings in the [php manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$fileName = 'file-2018-02-19-second.json';
preg_match('#([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))#is', $fileName, 
$output);
if (!empty($output)) {
    $date = preg_replace('#-#is', '', $output[1]);
    echo $date;
}
```

hope can help you!

related link: https://www.regextester.com/96683

Comment: No need to overcomplicate the date regex.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1 - Match & Replace

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##LY29DoIwFEZ3nuIOJBfU8hcHFQ2Lm4kvIMaQUiwGexuKk/HZa/lZzvSd82mprT0WWmrP8xsFJ8Cm7QTLknTHkoyle2YEJ1VHL0MK82Wke/F8vKuBywDjaDUp5aWsv9sfc8wWxrgBJzhQmHuCS4LWGDEEPt2SewjFHOqF7iouXKo8r0cHR2@eHACvBNMVNPRRNebW/gE)

```
<?php

$fn = 'file-2018-02-1-second.json';
$fn = preg_match('/.*file-\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/', $fn, $o);
echo isset($o[0]) ? preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $o[0]) : 'No match found';
```

#### Option 2 - Group & Concatenate

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwFET3OcVfFJKKSZvoQq3SG3iBWkTS1FQ0P5i6Es8eaxTczIPHDOOtj3Fbe@sJyXoHO6D9cDVclXLFS8Xlmgej0XXiEtDR6lfyd3M@3k6jtowWYpYm7NA9l688Uf1Z0DlMoykwr4jRFmEIwYwsw0a2H92oLxZtDjUkLZIVScIG6B4hvUGPD9fRKsY3)

```
<?php

$fn = 'file-2018-02-1-second.json';
$fn = preg_match('/.*file-(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/', $fn, $o);
echo isset($o[1], $o[2], $o[3]) ? $o[1].$o[2].$o[3] : 'No match found';
```

#### Explanation of Patterns

```
.*file-\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `file-` Match this literally
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.
- `\d{4}` Match any digit exactly 4 times
- `-` Match this literally
- `\d{2}` Match any digit exactly 2 times
- `-` Match this literally
- `\d{2}` Match any digit exactly 2 times

The second pattern `\D+` simply matches any non-digit character one or more times for replacement.

The last pattern (from option 2) is really just the simplified version of the first pattern I described, but groups each number part into capture groups.

Result: `20180219`

Comment: I used .*file-(\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-.*json regex for the file file-2018-02-19-second.json . it took a group 2018-02-19 , I need a group with 20180219 . How can I do it

Comment: @SanthoshChakka did you read the full code I posted? You can't do it in one regex. See the two links I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be solely about data extract, not about data validation.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dTIlo))

```
$file = 'file-2018-02-19-second.json';
$date = preg_replace('~\D+~', '', $file);
echo $date;
```

Output:

```
20180219
```

---

If you need slightly more accuracy/validation than that (leveraging the location of `file-`, you can use `\G` to extract the date components before imploding them.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/plMnd)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zGFRaH/1))

```
$file = 'somefile-2018-02-19-second.json';
echo preg_match_all('~\Gfile-\K\d+|-\K\d+~', $file, $out) ? implode($out[0]) : 'fail';
// same result as earlier method
```

Comment: If you have fringe cases where these methods fail, please update your question to provide the input string(s) that break my methods and I will adjust my answer.